# How to set an icon in MenuTrigger

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-menu

I have a menu icon in my navbar and I need to use it as a menu.

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this with the [react-native-popup-menu](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu) lib.

The component `<MenuTrigger />` only accepts text (strings) as prop.

How could I use an icon as a menu trigger?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually `MenuTrigger.text` is only optional property according to the [doc](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/39c28eeb380590effbcf6fed54b87bc3d9fa9646/doc/api.md#menutrigger)

> Optional | Text to be rendered. When this prop is provided, trigger's children won't be rendered

It is possible to place any content inside of `MenuTrigger` (if you don't use `text` property) like

```
<MenuTrigger>
  <YourIcon>
</MenuTrigger>
```

See also official [example](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/a36d274d20a31ba4519f5149a2ba6fe233dc937c/examples/Example.js#L62)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for asking, and posting the answer to this. I had the same question and solved it thanks to this post. 
I made a mock burger menu using this module. 
Having implemented this, my code now looks like this.

```
  <MenuTrigger>
  <Image 
      source={require('./assets/Burger.png')}
      >
      </Image>
  </MenuTrigger>
```

Note. I initially tried to wrap the Image> within a TouchableOpacity>, which triggered malfunctioning. Turns out there is no need to use . You only have to insert Image> directly.